# Why does moment.js not changing my timestamp into different timezone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have the following jquery script:

```
moment.tz.add('America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0');  

var mytime = 1443548496;
var newyc= moment.unix(mytime).tz('America/New_York').toDate(); //mg
alert(mytime);
alert(newyc);
```

and it doesn't work - I see the alert that prints the given timestamp first `1443548496` and then the time in my timezone instead of timezone America/New_York

```
Tue Sep 29 2015 19:40:56 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
```

Why it is not converted at this point and stored in a variable `newyc`?

Answer (score 0):

Include this to your script

> http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone.min.js

then

```
moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York");
```

Comment: I currently use `version : 2.10.2`, do you think it's better to use the older one? I tried including the `setDefault...` with my 2.10.2 but it didn't work..

Comment: i don't know but why using an old one ?

Comment: I'm asking because the one you suggested has the version number `version : 0.4.0` and the one I have (downloaded from github) is much newer (`2.0.2`)

Comment: i think it's a plugin for momentjs so you need the moment.js and that file too

Comment: oh sorry, you're right, I was using `0.3.0` of this js, I switched it to `0.4.0` but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The moment.js toDate() function does not set the time zone on the returned object:

```
// from moment.js
function toDate () {
    return this._offset ? new Date(+this) : this._d;
}
```

As a demonstration:

http://jsfiddle.net/b8o5cvdz/

```
$(function () {
    var timestamp = 1443545881; // Was 2015-09-29 11:58:01 America/Chicago
    var myMoment = moment.unix(timestamp).tz('Atlantic/Canary');
    var myDate = myMoment.toDate();
    alert('myMoment = ' + myMoment.toString());
    alert('myDate = ' + myDate);
});
```

As a question, if you are using moment.js and moment-timezone.js why do you want it back into a Javascript Date object?

Comment: I want it because later on I'm using it to fill a datetimepicker, for example I'm using: `var dd = newyc.getDate();` and other calculations on it, e.g. `now.setHours(now.getHours() + 2);`